# ASP.NET, Right way to use DataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader, datareader, advantage-database-server

I want to know right way to use DataReader. (C# and Advantage Database)

Assuming that I have Order,Item and Customer tables in my database.

and I need to read the data from each tables in a cs file.

So I opened the database connection and read data using DataReader.

like,

```
AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection("~~~~");
AdsCommand cmd;
AdsDataReader reader;

conn.open();
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from order";
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and Now I need to read the other table. but I think I need to close the connection and  reader and reconnect and redefine them.

So, I define the other reader.

```
conn.Close();
conn.Open();
AdsDataReader itemReader;
cmd.CommandText = " Select * from item";
itemReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

.
.
reader.close();
itemReader.close();
conn.Close();
```

Is it ok? using like this way? 
Anybody know better way, please advice me ~

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADO.NET 2.0 introduced a feature called MARS- Multiple Active Result Sets.  This allows you to submit multiple queries to the database and retrieve them with a single call.

Here is the MSDN article with a code sample that uses MARS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f(v=vs.80).aspx

Note that the connection string sets the MultipleActiveResultSets property to true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Advantage Database Connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets. :(

Answer (score 2):

(as the more appropriate answer was deleted)

You can keep the Connection open but you should, as a matter of good practice, close the Command and the Reader as soon as possible.

Best way is to put of each these resources in a `using() { }` statement.

If it is for instance possible or beneficial to put each query in a separate method, then use a separate Connection for each connection. As long as your db supports connection-pooling there will be  no loss in performance.

One more points:

- don't use `SELECT *`, spell out the columns

Comment: Aha! so if put the resources into using() then I do not have to close them at all? ^^ tyty!

Comment: Exactly, and it's exception-safe and the vars are nicely local to the block etc.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest u to learn or use SQLHelper

http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/source/SqlHelper-Source-Code-cs.html